# How to detect what instruction caused "truffle test" to result in "invalid opcode" error?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract

I wrote a test for my contract and it returns `invalid opcode` as a result.
Full output:

```
1) Contract: FPCoin1 One can purchase tokens for ether:
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
  at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:37312:16)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:220420:36
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:204149:9
  at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:205574:13)
  at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73069:18)
  at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73359:12)
  at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73514:12)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73474:24)
```

It tells me no particular information which instruction or line caused the problem.
Is it possible to actually see what went wrong?

Comment: `truffle compile` passes with no problems

Comment: Invalid op code results from an error thrown due to invalid arguments or conditions (such as invalid permissions) when the function is called, which would not be picked up by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t really get much feedback from a truffle test if an error is thrown from within a function’s execution.

You can do some simple quick checks to verify you have provided valid arguments to the function, such as double checking any `require`, `assert`, or any `reverts` anywhere and figuring out what’s getting passed in.  Also if there are any modifiers (eg `onlyOwner` or `payable`), conditions or permissions for calling the function. Or any math operations that may result in number overflows.

If that doesn’t help, you can use the debugger tool in remix ([https://remix.ethereum.org](https://remix.ethereum.org/)) and walk through function execution step by step.

Answer (score 0):

It actually tells you a lot of information.

In your Mocha script, find the `it` which says `FPCoin1 One can purchase tokens for ether` (the beginning of this string is possibly located at the enclosing `describe` level).

Inside that `it`, there is a `web3` call which eventually leads to a VM Exception.

Typically, you should strive for a minimal amount of `web3` calls inside each `it`.

If that is indeed the case, then it shouldn't be hard to isolate the one causing the problem.

Otherwise, put each `web3` call in a `try`/`catch` clause and find the rogue one.

Or even easier, print a unique string after each `web3` call, run the test and find the first string which is not printed (the rogue `web3` call would be the one that appears right before that string is printed).